# C# regex get url

Tags: regex, url, get

I use C# to get some sites from bing.com. And i used regex:

```
MatchCollection list_rv_url = Regex.Matches(htmlCode, @"<cite>(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)</cite>");
```

I only receive

```
www.example.com and example.com.
```

I want to get

```
http://example.com, https://example.com,http://www.example.com, https://www.example.com
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Provide your input string?

Comment: Reading sources from bing.com http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip%3A118.69.123.137&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=ip%3A118.69.123.137&sc=0-3&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=5673cc21ba424b61882db602c412f467

Answer (score 1):

Include `/` in your match pattern:

```
Regex.Matches(htmlCode, @"<cite>(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@/]+)</cite>");
                                                     ^
```